# Prevent <ENTER> from bubbling up from SuggestBox

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I want to prevent that when the user hits **ENTER** to select a Suggestion in the SuggestBox, that this Key event is bubbling up.

I have this code in the wrapping `Composite` :

```
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
            if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.KEYEVENTS) {
                int key = event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode();
                if (key == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                    event.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But this handler is never called.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? GWT event handler is not affected by event bubbling as per this [GWT FAQ](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_UI#How_can_I_efficiently_handle_events_from_many_interior_Widgets?).

Comment: @GaneshKumar because there is an outer widget that saves the form upon ENTER and this is triggered when using <ENTER> to select a Suggestion in the SuggestBox contained in this form.

Comment: Can you provide the complete sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why your method is not working. But I have an alternative approach. Add a key event listener for suggest box. If the enter key is pressed, cancel the propagation of the event.

```
suggestBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            int key = event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked better for me:

```
suggestBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                int key = event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode();
                if (key == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                    event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you explain the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

@Jen,

This code restricts the action of the 'enter' key-press in the textarea (if suggestBox associates with the text area),  even when suggestion list is not shown.

While my suggestion list is showing, pressing the 'ENTER' key triggered the event-handler addSelectionHandler() where I want to stop the propagation (addKeyPressHandler event-handler should not be triggered)